# How to get properties in Polymer content element?

Tags: javascript, polymer

Probably something super easy, but I seem unable to find the answer.

I would like to replace the properties in the `<content>` section. But I don't understand how to push the `title` (with content `hola`) to the `<content>` section.

demo-app.html

```
<dom-module id="demo-app">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
    <my-el>
      [[title]] or {{title}}
    </my-el>
  </template>
...
```

my-el.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="my-el">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
    <content></content>
  </template>

  <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'my-el',
        properties: {
          title: {
            type: String,
            value: 'hola',
          },
        }
      })
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

PS:
I'm 99% sure there are some docs that I'm missing... Any link is welcome :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's technically possible if `<demo-app>` had its own `title` property that you bound to `<my-el>.title` like this:

```html
<dom-module id="demo-app">
  <template>
    <my-el title="{{title}}">
      [[title]] or {{title}}
    </my-el>
    ...
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-el',
    properties: {
      title: {
        type: String,
        value: 'Hello world!',
        notify: true
      }
    }
  });
  
  Polymer({
    is: 'demo-app'
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <demo-app></demo-app>

  <dom-module id="demo-app">
    <template>
      <style>
        h1 {
          color: blue;
        }
      </style>
      <my-el title="{{title}}">
        <h1>[[title]]</h1>
      </my-el>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
  
  <dom-module id="my-el">
    <template>
      <content></content>
      <section>
        <input type="text" value="{{title::input}}">
      </section>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/pNpexE?editors=1010)

Comment: Aha thanks, but what if I don't know the available elements in advance? Ie. The come in through a REST API call

Comment: Can I also get the content, replace the [[]] and replace it?

Comment: Hmm. You're fetching HTML from a REST API? Or you're picking the elements to display based on data from a REST API call?

Comment: Re: content: I believe you can query the distributed nodes (from `<content>`) but not replace it. Here's the available DOM APIs: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#light-dom-children

Comment: There is an API of which the result contains `title` and many other things. This is what I would like to replace inside the content element.

Comment: Yeah, sounds wrong :) I would create an element and bind the necessary properties instead of using `<content>`.

Comment: Aha, so instead of using `[[title]]` i might use `<sub-el sometag="title"></sub-el>`

Comment: Well, you'd use `<sub-el sometag="[[title]]"></sub-el>` (brackets still needed)